# How can I check to see if provided class exists

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using Provider package in my flutter app.

I am conditionally providing a ChangeNotifier class using provider.

A subsequent build method down the tree wants to check to see if the class exists, and it is not a failure case if it doesn't.

How can I do this using Provider package. Currently when I call...

```
Provider.of<MyChangeNotifier>(context);
```

It throws if MyChangeNotifier does not exist up the tree. All I want is a quick and simple check for MyChangeNotifier existence, because it is an expected case.

Comment: you can try implementing the second point mentioned in https://pub.dev/packages/provider/versions/6.0.0-dev/changelog  of the latest provider version

Comment: @CalvinGonsalves. You have provided the correct answer. The way to do this is to call Provider.of<MyChangeNotifier?>(context) with nullable types language feature enabled. If you want to write that as the answer, you can get some internet points.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Scorb mentioned, calling `Provider.of<MyChangeNotifier?>(context)` with null safety enabled will try to obtain the matching provider and if none are found `null` will be returned instead of throwing.

Comment: hahaha, how did I not figure this one out myself

Comment: note that you will have to use provider 6.0.0 or later for this to work