# Check if a cubit is in the context

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

is there a way to check if a cubit/bloc is available in the current context.
I have a widget which is used in different pages/widgets, an some of the pages are using a cubit, but not all.

I need the state of the cubit, but only if a cubit is available.

```
if (context.read<MyCubit>().state) {
```

The context.read method throws an error when the cubit is not available.

So what I need is a method to check if a cubit is in the context.

Comment: I don't know a neat way to do that.What about writing a separate function and wrapping ```context.read<MyCubit>().state``` inside a ```try catch ``` clause ? return false when an ```Exception``` occures.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible to do that with try catch, but i that a clean solution.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68369060/how-can-i-check-to-see-if-provided-class-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using

```
Provider.of<MyCubit?>(context)
```

will return null if `MyCubit` does not exist in the context